# Relation between row rank and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

If an $m$ x $n$ matrix ($m \le n$) has full row rank, then is the column space the same as $\mathbb R^m$? Please prove (or provide a counterexample).

Is there a general property of subspaces that makes the answer to the above question obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

The general property is that the row-rank is the dimension of the image (the range) of the matrix.  Of course, the only $m$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^m$ is $\Bbb R^m$.